# How can I fix this problem in React with import/export?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, export, undefined

I'm working with my colleague on the project and everything works on his PC, but not on mine. I got this bug:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 

You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or 
you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

It seems to be a problem with import/export but I can't find this.
Can you please help me?

File `index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { App } from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

File `app.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';

import { AppMainWrapper } from './modules/AppMainWrapper/AppMainWrapper.component';


export const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <DocumentTitle title="Finn den råeste roomie med oss">
            <AppMainWrapper />
        </DocumentTitle>
    );
};
```

AppMainWrapperComponent.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import { getBaseUrl, routes } from '../../routes/routes';
import { Footer } from '../components/Footer/Footer.component';

import { Home } from './components/Home/Home.component';
import { Login } from './components/Login/Login.component';
import { NewUser } from './components/NewUser/NewUser.component';


export const AppMainWrapper: React.FC = () => {
    const { main } = routes;

    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        path={getBaseUrl()}
                        exact
                        component={Home}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={main.login.path}
                        component={Login}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={main.newUser.path}
                        component={NewUser}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
};
```

I have no idea what can be wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the content of `AppMainWrapper.component`?

Comment: From the error we only can guess it should be an unnamed export: `import AppMainWrapper from '.../'`

Comment: No. I tried this as well, but I got error from Eslint straightaway.